# Upgrade MySQL server on local machine

Tags: mysql

We have a system running on Java and a MySQL server on a Linux server.

On my local Windows 10 machine, I have this system running by just installing MySQL Workbench and ampps. I have not installed anything else.
The mysql version on my local computer is 5.6.37, but the server runs on version 5.7.20

How do I upgrade my local version from 5.6.37 to 5.7.20?

Answer (score 0):

Use following steps for version w.x.y-z

```
wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_w.x.y-z_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_w.x.y-z_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

After installation

```
mysql_upgrade
```

Then

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry, I forgot to mention that I run my system on a windows-machine.

Comment: Try this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-upgrading.html

Comment: I saw this page, but I do not have the C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6 installed, just mysqlworkbench.